# Visual Studio ASP.net MVC Jquery version issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2012

I have a javascript/html code that works fine in a separate html file, and works fine on JSFiddle BUT when I try it on my project in a view, it doesnt work! I think it's a JQuery version-related issue. I have the latest version, I removed it and installed the 1.8.3 and the 1.7.1 but it's still not working! Do you have any idea or a way to fix it? It's driving me crazy!

Here's  the link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bn3K/  DRAG AND DROP UPLOAD

http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/  JQUERY TAGS INPUT PLUGIN

Visual Studio 2012 Express 2012 for Web, MVC 4 Internet Application...

PS: I tried

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Layout Page**

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
</head>
```

Edit:

I downloaded the filedrop project and run it on Visual Studio... the upload drag and drop worked! this is the view page source of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
#dropZone {
    background: gray;
    border: black dashed 3px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dropZone').filedrop({
        url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
        paramname: 'files',
        maxFiles: 5,
        dragOver: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'blue');
        },
        dragLeave: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        drop: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        afterAll: function () {
            $('#dropZone').html('The file(s) have been uploaded successfully!');
        },
        uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
            $('#uploadResult').append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
});
</script>


<h2>File Drag & Drop Upload Demo</h2>
<div id="dropZone">Drop your files here</div>
<br/>
Uploaded Files:
<ul id="uploadResult">

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And it's still not working in my project! this is the view page source of my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />         


    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Mocodis</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">


            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">






<style type="text/css">
#dropZone {
    background: gray;
    border: black dashed 3px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dropZone').filedrop({
        url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
        paramname: 'files',
        maxFiles: 5,
        dragOver: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'blue');
        },
        dragLeave: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        drop: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        afterAll: function () {
            $('#dropZone').html('The file(s) have been uploaded successfully!');
        },
        uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
            $('#uploadResult').append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
});
</script>


<h2>File Drag & Drop Upload Demo</h2>
<div id="dropZone">Drop your files here</div>
<br/>
Uploaded Files:
<ul id="uploadResult">

</ul>

        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; 2013 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your MVC page showing where the script is placed? The placement of js scripts within the page is very important. What version of MVC are you using (Razor, or older)?

Comment: MVC 4 yes Razor, where should I place the js scripts in the page? I always put them at the beginning

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> THE JS FUNCTIONS HERE <script />

Comment: Look for the libraries on the `Layout Page`.

Comment: on the Layout Page I have this: <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>

Comment: Where on your layout page do you have the reference to jQuery?

Comment: "Beginning" is too vague. Are you able to post the view html? As you are using Razor, you might as well add a new bundle for JQuery into App_Start\BundleConfig.cs and include that in the layout page. It is likely you will use JQuery on multiple pages (if not all) by the time you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Without full code I can only suggest a few changes to try:

1. add `type="text/javascript"` to your original `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>` as it appears to be missing.
2. Add JQuery via a new bundle instead (this also gets the best of JS compression and version control features automatically):

### e.g. add this to App_Start\BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
```

and put this into your Views/shared/_layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

To test with uncompressed/uncached files add this to the end of `RegisterBundles()`

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

3. Use Fiddler2 to see what requests are actually being made (i.e. is it actually requesting your js files)

Comment: Actually in the BundleConfig.cs there is already the jquery bundle, so I only added the enable optimizations = false at the end. In the layout, scripts.render is already there...

Comment: In fact I created a whole new project just for the drag and drop thing just to make sure there is nothing wrong with my project, and I added the type=text/javascript but same result! It's weird, I will try Fiddler2 to see what's really happening. Thank you!

Comment: @christian abijaber: What does fiddler2 show now? If you get any 404s it may have incorrect URLs or be pulling in the wrong JQuery version if it was an old project.

Comment: Fiddler2 shows the get requests for jquery 1.8.3 and the javascript for the drag and drop upload. it's all 304 so I dont have any 404 errors! I downloaded the full project for the drag and drop uload and run it through visual studio, it worked! I will edit my post and show you  the view source page of it, and below it, I will put the view source page of my project maybe you'll find the problem! Thank you a lot